# Django DateTimeField TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know there are many posts about this error. Such as: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737221/expected-string-or-buffer-date-re-matchvalue-django-error) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220480/django-datetime-migration-error)

But I knew already that. And that's why I'm getting crazy.

When I create an instance and try to save it, I don't have problems:

```
per_detail.preview_title = per_detail.details_sample.preview_title
per_detail.icon = per_detail.details_sample.icon
per_detail.content = fill_content(per_detail)
per_detail.save()
```

easy.

But when there's already the instance, and I try to save it again (updated it). Then I get this error:

> ```
> match = datetime_re.match(value)
> ```
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

whit this code:

```
personal_detail_sample = kwargs['instance']
        personal_details = PersonalDetail.objects.filter(Q(details_sample=personal_detail_sample))
        for per_detail in personal_details:
            per_detail_updated = fill_updated_content(personal_detail_sample, per_detail)
            per_detail_updated.save()
```

I gotta say, it doesn't matter where I try to update that instance, I get always the same error. (so, it's not because the `kwargs['instance']`)

And here's the field, that is giving troubles:

`sent_date = models.DateTimeField(_('sent_date'), null=True, blank=True)`

As you maybe noticed, I never filled the field "sent_date", but it should be null. So it shouldn't be a problem. And for just being safe, I also tried to do:

```
per_detail.sent_date = *a date*
per_detail.save()
```

And I'm getting the same error.

I don't have any idea what could it be.

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: `value` is not a string or bytes-like object (maybe it's Unicode, maybe it's a Django field type - didn't read you question in enough detail), in any case you should probably print its value/type/repr - or set a breakpoint and inspect it...

Comment: remove auto_now_add and try again

Comment: No chance... I removed the auto_now_add and I debugged and I got ```sent_date = None``` which for a database would be "null" and I permit it. I made "makemigrations" and "migrate" several times, just in case, and same result. :( I don't have any idea...

Comment: I also did ```per_detail_updated.sent_date = datetime.datetime.now()``` with ```sent_date = 2017-03-24 20:37:48.584796``` (debugged) and got the same error. I'm thinking about erasing every migrations and makemigrations again...

Comment: Erasing the migrations and making it again resolved nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an error in the field "date" not "sent_date".

I'm pretty sorry. The field of "date" in the **models.py** was:

`date = models.DateTimeField(_('date'), auto_now_add=True)` but in the DataBase was `time without time zone` and not `timestamp without time zone`. Why? Who knows...

I deleted the `sent_date` field, and saw, that there was another error with a date, and that's why I found the error.

Many thanks to the people that tried to help!